# Why does my React Slider call my function twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, slider

I am rendering a Chakra UI slider and line graph on my page. When I stop moving the slider, it should call a function that updates the state and then calls another function which updates the value of a constant. That constant is then used as the yAxis of my line graph. (The xAxis is already defined.) However, when I stop moving the slider, the calculateEvent function seems to be called twice. Why does this happen?

```
<Input 
     label="Initial Savings amount" 
     name="Initial Savings" 
     onInput={e => changeInitialSavings(e.currentTarget.value)} 
     placeholder="5000"
/>
<Input 
     label="Monthly Deposit" 
     name="Monthly Deposit" 
     onInput={e => changeMonthlyDepo(e.currentTarget.value)} 
     placeholder="100"
/>
<Slider
    label="Interest Rate"
    name="Interest Rate"
    defaultValue={2}
    min={1}
    max={15}
    step={1}
    onChangeEnd={e => changeInterestRate(e)} 
/>
<LineChart
    title="Savings Over time"
    xAxisData={xAxis}
    yAxisData={yAxis}
    xLabel="Years"
    yLabel="Amount"
/>

const changeInitialSavings = (event : string) => {
    setInitialSavings(event);
    calculateEvent();
}

const changeMonthlyDepo = (event : string) => {
    setMonthlyDepo(event);
    calculateEvent();
}

const changeInterestRate = (event : number) => {
    setInterestRate(event);
    calculateEvent();
}

const calculateEvent = () => {
    console.log("Calculate event called with slider value: ", interest);
    yAxis = [interest, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: If it was invoked twice then I would kind of expect to see two identical logs, but this isn't the case. Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue for us to live debug in?

Comment: I assume that is because `setInterestRate` is a useState action that causes a re-render to the component

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry, I can't reproduce it as the overall file structure is a little complex, but the (2) on the left hand side of the logs show that two identical logs are being produced each time an event is called.

Comment: @Eldshe Yes, you're right that setInterestRate is a useState action. Is there a way that I can prevent that re-render from happening and calling my calculateEvent function twice?

Comment: Oof, total fail on my part, sorry. I think even with `setInterestRate` enqueueing a state update the `calculateEvent` function is still only invoked once in this code snippet. Is something else also calling `calculateEvent`?

Comment: @DrewReese Two other inputs are being rendered alongside the Slider and Linegraph, both of which call a function `onChange` that is almost identical to `changeInterestRate` (calling a useState action then calling `calculateEvent`, although the event type is a string instead. When I `console.log` the slider output instead of calling `setInterestRate`, it correctly produces one log.

Comment: Well, I meant more, do you have any `useEffect` calls or anything in the body of your component also calling `calculateEvent`. Basically it seems you have some unauthorized/unintentional side-effect from the state update. Can you include an example snippet of all the places that reference `calculateEvent` and functions that invoke them?

Comment: @DrewReese I've edited the code snippet to include all the functions which call `calculateEvent`. There are no `useEffect` calls calling `calculateEvent`.